# What is the "right" way to cache HTTP data between JavaScript and Java Servlets?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, servlets, http-caching

I am developing a client-server app with a JavaScript client and a Java Servlet running in Apache Tomcat.  I am developing both ends, so I hope to do things the "right" way.

My JavaScript uses XMLHttpRequest.  It seems like XMLHttpRequest does not do caching for me, so I used IndexedDB to cache responses. IndexDB is working sweetly for me in all the browsers I need to support (iOS, Android, PC, Mac).

I really want to manage cache validity with ETag values, so I tried this...

```
public class MyServlet_Etag extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String etag = myEtag(request);

        String inm = request.getHeader("If-None-Match");
        if (inm != null && inm.equals(etag))
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
        else {
            byte[] data = myData(request);
            response.setHeader("ETag", etag);
            response.getOutputStream().write(data);
            response.setContentLength(data.length);
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }
}
```

... but Tomcat strips out my "ETag" headers.  So I tried this...

```
public class MyServlet_LastModified extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        byte[] data = myData(request);
        response.getOutputStream().write(data);
        response.setContentLength(data.length);
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    @Override
    protected long getLastModified(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return myLastModified(request);
    }
}
```

The above Servlet code is simple, and in JavaScript I can manage my IndexedDB cache with the following code:

```
refreshURI = function(uri,lastModified,onRead) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", uri, true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    req.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", lastModified);
    var _this = this;
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            var hundred = Math.floor(req.status / 100);
            if (hundred == 2) {
                var response = req.response;
                var lastModified = req.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
                myIndexedDB.write(uri, req.response, lastModified);// Update our cache
                onRead(response, lastModified);
            } else if (hundred == 3) {
                // No recent change, so skip further processing 
            }
        }
    };

};
```

So my app is working. But it can only handle 1 update per second, because the Last-Modified resolution is 1 second in HTTP's date format.  I want to support many updates per second.  I could use fake Last-Modified values that update by 1 second each update.  But this is not the "right" way!

Q1. Is there some way to stop Tomcat stripping out my ETag values?

Q2. Is it acceptable to use fake Last-Modified HTTP header values between my JavaScript and my Servlet?

Q3. What is the right way to cache HTTP responses between a JavaScipt client and a Java Servlet?

Comment: Do the ajax calls really impact your perormance or did the optimization do?

Comment: I am developing a live mapping system with WebGL graphics, so the users can query and edit the map while offline, and save edits when back online.  The clients need MBs of data tiles as they pan and zoom, which will only change if someone else has edited the map in that region.  So, yes I do need caching.   I agree that many other JS apps might not really need caching.